# Error on Include php:/usr/share/pear

Tags: php, functions

I'm trying to work with an old plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ecards/ (I'm not the plugin author) and I get this error in the php error log and a blank screen when trying to view the e-card on site:

```
 Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
 in /home/public_html/demo/wp-content/plugins/wp-ecards/ft-wp-ecards.php on line 171
```

**I don't know what is happening. Is this plugin trying to load the pear library? Any ideas?**

The function around line 171 is below (with line 171 marked as such) :

```
function init_wpecards_viewcard(){
    global $wp_query;
    if ( isset($wp_query->query_vars['ft_wpecards_view']) ){
        if ( $ft_wpecards_parentpost = ft_wpecards_get_post_id($wp_query->query_vars['card']) ){
            if ( ft_wpecards_get_post_type($wp_query->query_vars['card']) == 'post' ) {
                query_posts("p=".$ft_wpecards_parentpost."&ft_wpecards_view=1&card=".$wp_query->query_vars['card']);
                include(get_single_template());  
                //exit;
            }else{


    query_posts("page_id=".$ft_wpecards_parentpost."&ft_wpecards_view=1&card=".$wp_query->query_vars['card']);
                    include(get_page_template()); //LINE 171
                    //exit;
                }
            }else{
                include(get_404_template());
            }
            exit;
        }
        //die('tr');
    }
    add_action('template_redirect','init_wpecards_viewcard');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it not make more sense to use get_template_part() ? What may be happening is that there is no 404 template:

> ```
> if ( '' != get_query_template( '404' ) )
>    include( get_query_template( '404' ) );
> ```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_template

This may be because pretty permalinks have been turned off, or because there is no 404 page template to be found.

The same is true of your get_page_template:

- You called query_posts but you did not call wp_Reset_query afterwards
- get_page_template must be called within the post loop, yet there is no post loop to be found
- you have the ID, it would be far easier to do a `get_post_meta($ft_wpecards_parentpost,'_wp_page_template',true);` to grab the page template filename, prefixed with the theme folder url

Comment: Thanks, I'm not the original plugin author; I'm just trying to get it to work. I do have a 404 and permalinks are on. The plugin will generate an e-card, but actually viewing the e-card URL is broken. The plugin is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ecards/

Comment: As I said, `include(get_page_template());` needs to be inside the post loop, but you haven't got a post loop, you've left it out, the whole have_posts() the_post() etc?

Comment: `get_page_template()` doesn't have to be called within the loop, it actually uses `get_queried_object_id()` which is accessible very early on. But otherwise, I think Tom is right on. It says "Failed including ''"; which indicates that `get_page_template()` is returning an empty string, indicating that - most likely - the code is being called somewhere other than on a Page.